# the tables i have created in sqlplus not appearing in Navicat lite

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, navicat

Guys I am using oracle 11g and I am pretty new with it.

the problem is when I try to create a table and insert a value in sqlplus terminal, it is not showing in the Navicat lite(Graphical representation software).

Here, let me make this more clear by showing you the pictures.

here are the rows that are getting printed on SQLPlus terminal

[image]

But take a look at the rows in the Navicat

[image]

Here the table name is TIME.

Can anyone explain to me what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you didn't

```
commit;
```

in SQL*Plus after inserting rows. Unless you do that, those values are visible only to you, but not other sessions (which is what Navicat sees). So - commit.

---

As of letter case and double quotes:

This is how you should be doing it - don't use double quotes, reference tables any way you want:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> select * from TEST;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> select * from tEsT;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.
```

If you use double quotes, you have to reference the table exactly the same way as you created it:

```
SQL> create table "test" (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);
insert into test (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> insert into TEST (id) values (1);
insert into TEST (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> insert into "TEST" (id) values (1);
insert into "TEST" (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> insert into "test" (id) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: That's amazing. I was banging my head to solve this problem. But now I just want to thank you a lot.

Comment: Hey, small problem. Now if i create a table in Navicat i am not able to see it Sql plus but the other way around is working perfectly after using commit;

Comment: its saying ERROR:                                                                                                                  ORA-04043: object test_2 does not exist

Comment: test_2 is a table created in navicat

Comment: Did you, by any chance, enclose table name into double quotes? If so, don't do that. Oracle doesn't like it much.

Comment: Oh no no, I didn't do that. But with a little bit of work, I got to know that I should only save table names in uppercase. else the SQL plus won't recognize the tables.

Comment: Not really. I added an example which shows how it goes; have a look, please.

Comment: Oh no, I think you misunderstood. What I was saying is that if I create a table in Navicat software with lower case letters then I am not able to see or use that table in SQL plus. But hey, thanks for the update in the answer I got more understanding.